# Submit form delay with mousedown with cancel on mouseup

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Im trying to create a form that will submit with a long press (currently 2 seconds) but being able to cancel (or prevent submitting the form) when the user stops holding the submit button to give the user time to change their mind about submitting the form.

```
function conf_submit(btn) {

$(btn).mousedown(function() {
btn_timeout = setTimeout(function() {
  alert("form submitted");
}, 2000);
$(this).val("Release to cancel!");
$(this).attr('class', 'btn_down');
});

$(btn).mouseup(function() {
clearTimeout(btn_timeout);
$(this).val("Submit");
$(this).attr('class', 'btn_up');
});
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/lokifiddle/gthLr0vy/2/)

The button is suppose to change text, i wanted to have a count down after 'Release to cancel!' so the user knows how long until the form submits but couldn't get this to work.

My problem is; The first time you click the link it doesnt fire, it also continues to fire even on mouseup.

Thanks in advance for any support.

Comment: Don't assign new handlers every time the button is clicked.  Don't do it onclick at all.  Just do it when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `conf_submit` once with the button element when page loads, not each time the button is clicked.

```js
function conf_submit(btn) {

  $(btn).mousedown(function() {
    btn_timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      alert("form submitted");
    }, 2000);
    $(this).val("Release to cancel!");
    $(this).attr('class', 'btn_down');
  });

  $(btn).mouseup(function() {
    clearTimeout(btn_timeout);
    $(this).val("Submit");
    $(this).attr('class', 'btn_up');
  });
}

[...document.querySelectorAll(".btn_longpress")].forEach(conf_submit);
```

```css
.btn_down {
  background-color: red;
}

.btn_up {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input class="btn_up btn_longpress" type="button" value="Submit" />
  <input class="btn_up btn_longpress" type="button" value="Submit2" />
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. My page contains multiple buttons with different IDs so is the line conf_submit(document.querySelector("#btnTesting")); still valid? or would i do conf_submit(document.querySelectorAll());

Comment: Yes, using a class would be a good way to hook up several buttons.  In the edit I added the class "btn_longpress" and the wrapper so that all such buttons get this behavior.